I don't see the menu entries for releases
Using Azure Devops, I'm trying to create a CD/CD pipeline.
In an ideal scenario, the situation should typically unfold like this:

However, contrary to expectations, the current scenario is quite different, manifesting itself in this way:

What's wrong here?

This question is similar to: AzureDevOps Pipeline 'Classic Editor' not visible when trying to create a pipeline. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can go to "Organization Settings" (and "Project Settings") > "Pipelines" > "Settings" to check whether the option "Disable creation of classic release pipelines" is turned on. If so, turn it off.

When the option "Disable creation of classic release pipelines" is turned on:

If there is no any existing classic release pipeline in a project, you cannot see the 'Releases' option under Pipelines section and also cannot create new release pipelines within this project.
If there are existing classic release pipelines in a project, you can see the 'Releases' option under Pipelines section but cannot create new release pipelines within this project.

In addition:

When this option is turned on at "Organization Settings", it will affect all projects within the current organization, and you cannot turn it off at "Project Settings" of each project.
When this option is turned off at "Organization Settings", you can turn it on/off at "Project Settings" of each project.


